# Wireless network not shown in elementary OS 5.0 Juno

Tags: release-juno, wifi, networking

I have recently installed elementary OS 5.0 juno. I could not find any wireless network for accessing internet. Unfortunately I was not able to install wireless driver, moreover I tried almost every solution posted in this group for that issue but they did not solve my problems also. Here is output of wireless-info.txt file

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 16 Oct 2019 18:49 CEST +0200

Booted last: 16 Oct 2019 00:00 CEST +0200

Script from: 22 Oct 2018 03:34 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: elementary
Description:    elementary OS 5.0 Juno
Release:    5.0
Codename:   juno

##### kernel ############################

Linux 4.15.0-65-generic #74-Ubuntu SMP Tue Sep 17 17:06:04 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=1

##### desktop ###########################

Pantheon

##### lspci #############################

02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [103c:804a]
    Kernel modules: wl

03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 07)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller [103c:80cc]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 002 Device 003: ID 04f2:b52d Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0438:7900 Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0a5c:216d Broadcom Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0438:7900 Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

##### secure boot #######################

SecureBoot enabled

##### lsmod #############################

hp_wmi                 16384  0
sparse_keymap          16384  1 hp_wmi
wmi_bmof               16384  0
cfg80211              622592  0
wmi                    24576  2 hp_wmi,wmi_bmof

##### interfaces ########################

[/etc/network/interfaces]
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### ifconfig ##########################

1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback <MAC address> brd <MAC address>
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp3s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether <MAC 'enp3s0' [IF1]> brd <MAC address>
    inet 192.168.0.43/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute enp3s0
       valid_lft 85026sec preferred_lft 85026sec
    inet6 2a02:ab88:153f:1780:193:1823:a722:a49a/64 scope global temporary dynamic 
       valid_lft 603428sec preferred_lft 84449sec
    inet6 2a02:ab88:153f:1780:3358:7e73:48a0:899/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute 
       valid_lft 1039523sec preferred_lft 434723sec
    inet6 fe80::9c03:6c36:544d:eaa7/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

##### iwconfig ##########################

lo        no wireless extensions.

enp3s0    no wireless extensions.

##### route #############################

default via 192.168.0.1 dev enp3s0 proto dhcp metric 100 
169.254.0.0/16 dev enp3s0 scope link metric 1000 
192.168.0.0/24 dev enp3s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.43 metric 100 

##### resolv.conf #######################

[644 root '/etc/resolv.conf']
search local
nameserver 127.0.0.53

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager

Running:

root       645     1  0 18:15 ?        00:00:01 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

##### NetworkManager info ###############

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         enp3s0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceEthernet
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         r8169
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 2.3LK-NAPI
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               --
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'enp3s0' [IF1]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.5/0000:03:00.0/net/enp3s0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       enp3s0
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     Wired connection 1
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       5003a7d2-6419-33fc-b9c7-abbadab8e098
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/2
GENERAL.METERED:                        no (guessed)
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     100 Mb/s
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
CAPABILITIES.SRIOV:                     no
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               on
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         192.168.0.43/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            192.168.0.1
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 0.0.0.0/0, nh = 192.168.0.1, mt = 100
IP4.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = 192.168.0.0/24, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 100
IP4.ROUTE[3]:                           dst = 169.254.0.0/16, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 1000
IP4.DNS[1]:                             192.168.0.1
IP4.DOMAIN[1]:                          local
DHCP4.OPTION[1]:                        domain_name_servers = 192.168.0.1
DHCP4.OPTION[2]:                        requested_domain_search = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[3]:                        requested_time_offset = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[4]:                        host_name = HP
DHCP4.OPTION[5]:                        requested_domain_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[6]:                        requested_rfc3442_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[7]:                        dhcp_lease_time = 86400
DHCP4.OPTION[8]:                        expiry = 1571329597
DHCP4.OPTION[9]:                        requested_netbios_scope = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[10]:                       next_server = 192.168.0.1
DHCP4.OPTION[11]:                       requested_wpad = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[12]:                       dhcp_message_type = 5
DHCP4.OPTION[13]:                       requested_interface_mtu = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[14]:                       domain_name = local
DHCP4.OPTION[15]:                       ip_address = 192.168.0.43
DHCP4.OPTION[16]:                       requested_subnet_mask = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[17]:                       requested_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[18]:                       subnet_mask = 255.255.255.0
DHCP4.OPTION[19]:                       requested_domain_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[20]:                       broadcast_address = 192.168.0.255
DHCP4.OPTION[21]:                       requested_ntp_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[22]:                       requested_netbios_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[23]:                       requested_broadcast_address = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[24]:                       requested_routers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[25]:                       requested_ms_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[26]:                       routers = 192.168.0.1
DHCP4.OPTION[27]:                       network_number = 192.168.0.0
DHCP4.OPTION[28]:                       requested_host_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[29]:                       dhcp_server_identifier = 192.168.0.1
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         2a02:ab88:153f:1780:193:1823:a722:a49a/64
IP6.ADDRESS[2]:                         2a02:ab88:153f:1780:3358:7e73:48a0:899/64
IP6.ADDRESS[3]:                         fe80::9c03:6c36:544d:eaa7/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            fe80::20b:ff:fe00:add0
IP6.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 2a02:ab88:153f:1780::/64, nh = ::, mt = 100
IP6.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = ::/0, nh = fe80::20b:ff:fe00:add0, mt = 100
IP6.ROUTE[3]:                           dst = ff00::/8, nh = ::, mt = 256, table=255
IP6.ROUTE[4]:                           dst = fe80::/64, nh = ::, mt = 256
IP6.ROUTE[5]:                           dst = fe80::/64, nh = ::, mt = 100
IP6.DNS[1]:                             2a02:ab88:153f:1780:20b:ff:fe00:add0
DHCP6.OPTION[1]:                        dhcp6_name_servers = 2a02:ab88:153f:1780:20b:ff:fe00:add0
DHCP6.OPTION[2]:                        requested_dhcp6_domain_search = 1
DHCP6.OPTION[3]:                        dhcp6_server_id = 0:1:0:1:25:36:ec:9c:22:27:88:34:5e:fb
DHCP6.OPTION[4]:                        requested_dhcp6_client_id = 1
DHCP6.OPTION[5]:                        requested_dhcp6_name_servers = 1
DHCP6.OPTION[6]:                        dhcp6_preference = 0
DHCP6.OPTION[7]:                        dhcp6_client_id = 0:4:9a:b6:b4:c6:18:11:c6:73:3d:32:5d:53:ef:69:d0:ef
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/{1}
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   5003a7d2-6419-33fc-b9c7-abbadab8e098 | Wired connection 1

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager config #############

[[/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf]]
[connection]
wifi.powersave = 3

[[/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf]]
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile
[ifupdown]
managed=false
[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-dns-resolved.conf]]
[main]
dns=systemd-resolved

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf]]
[keyfile]
unmanaged-devices=*,except:type:wifi,except:type:wwan

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/20-connectivity-ubuntu.conf]]
[connectivity]
uri=http://connectivity-check.ubuntu.com/

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/no-mac-addr-change.conf]]
[device-mac-addr-change-wifi]
match-device=driver:rtl8723bs,driver:rtl8189es,driver:r8188eu,driver:8188eu,driver:eagle_sdio,driver:wl
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no
wifi.cloned-mac-address=preserve
ethernet.cloned-mac-address=preserve

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

##### Netplan config ####################

[/etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml]
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: Europe/Budapest (based on set time zone)

global
country 00: DFS-UNSET
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 20), (N/A, 20), (N/A), AUTO-BW, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-OFDM, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5170 - 5250 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), AUTO-BW, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5250 - 5330 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, AUTO-BW, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5490 - 5730 @ 160), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5735 - 5835 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), PASSIVE-SCAN
    (57240 - 63720 @ 2160), (N/A, 0), (N/A)

##### iwlist channels ###################

lo        no frequency information.

enp3s0    no frequency information.

##### iwlist scan #######################

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

enp3s0    Interface doesn't support scanning.

##### module infos ######################

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.15.0-65-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
author:         Johannes Berg
srcversion:     268278B721485146AC7CB84
depends:        
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           cfg80211
vermagic:       4.15.0-65-generic SMP mod_unload 
signat:         PKCS#7
signer:         
sig_key:        
sig_hashalgo:   md4
parm:           bss_entries_limit:limit to number of scan BSS entries (per wiphy, default 1000) (int)
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

##### module parameters #################

[cfg80211]
bss_entries_limit: 1000
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00

##### /etc/modules ######################

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/amd64-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-bcm43.conf]
blacklist b43
blacklist b43legacy
blacklist ssb
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist brcm80211
blacklist brcmfmac
blacklist brcmsmac
blacklist bcma

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/broadcom-sta-common.conf]
blacklist b43
blacklist b43legacy
blacklist b44
blacklist bcma
blacklist brcm80211
blacklist brcmsmac
blacklist ssb
install wl /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install wl $CMDLINE_OPTS

[/etc/modprobe.d/intel-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

##### rc.local ##########################

grep: /etc/rc.local: No such file or directory

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

##### dmesg #############################

[  657.419046] r8169 0000:03:00.0 enp3s0: link down
[  723.022243] r8169 0000:03:00.0 enp3s0: link up

########## wireless info END ############
```

Comment: Try with `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` . Also you can use `sudo modprobe wl` to make sure the driver is loaded.

Comment: @Maccer, I got this error: modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'wl': Required key not available while running 'sudo modprobe wl'

Comment: According to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/762254/why-do-i-get-required-key-not-available-when-install-3rd-party-kernel-modules) the issue is that you have secure boot enabled so the kernel can't load the wireless driver. To solve it you can (easy) disable secure boot or (hard) sign the drivers following the procedure listed there.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It did work

Comment: Welcome to elementary OS SE! Why don't you grab the answer, post it here with a source link? So, others facing the same problem can get helped easily. Have  a nice day!

Comment: For disabling secure boot in UEFI (BIOS Settings) use this detailed info [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/762254/why-do-i-get-required-key-not-available-when-install-3rd-party-kernel-modules).